# Converge of a function of discrete random variables

Tags: probability

So we know that from the continuous mapping theorem if $f$ is a continuous function, converge of a sequence of random variables $(X_n ,n \in \mathbb{N})$ in any sense implies convergence of $f(X_n)$ in the same sense. So my question is what happens when $X_n$ are discrete random variables. That is, is there a theorem to guarantee convergence of $f(X_n)$ (where $f$ now is defined on $\mathbb{N}$) when $X_n$ converges, in the case that the $X_n$ random variables are discrete?

Comment: But the continuous mapping theorem says nothing about the $X_n$ having to be continuous? It should work equally well for discrete $X_n$.

Comment: Yes but what if function f is defined on $\mathbb {N}$?

Comment: Any function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{N}$ is continuous, so the theorem would work for such a function (of course, you need the range of your random variables to be contained in the domain of $f$).